# Initial state of beam before the collision in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

I'm on the chapter 5 of the Schwartz's QFT book, which is about cross sections.
In this chapter, one needs to calculate the following value:
$$\frac{|\langle i|S|f \rangle|^2}{\langle i | i\rangle \langle f | f \rangle}$$

Before and after the collision, $|i\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$ are assume to be free fields. In particular, $|i\rangle$ is assumed to be $a_{p_1}^+ a_{p_2}^+|0\rangle$ for some momentum $p_1$ and $p_2$ with on-shell conditions $p_1^2 = m^2$ and $p_2^2 = m^2$. But since the experiment is done in a finite volume $V$, $|i\rangle$ has some uncertainty. For this reason, $\langle p_1 | p_1 \rangle$ is valued as $(2E_{p_1}) V$, not $(2E_{p_1})(2\pi)^3 \delta^3(0)$. Using this trick, both numerator and denominator have finite values, and the calculation goes on.

In particular, if the beam has length $L$ and speed $v$, the collision occurs in the finite time $T=L/v$, so $\delta^4(0)$ is considered as $TV/(2\pi)^4$.

### Questions

I've heard that predictions of QED on scattering were confirmed with stunningly high precisions. I'm not sure that such rough estimation above using the uncertainty scale can fit data in those precisions.

1. Are such calculations are good enough to the data fitting?
2. If not, I wonder how the real stuffs work. For example, do we know the initial state of the beam before the collision in the form of:
   $$|i\rangle = \int d^3{\vec{p_1}} c_{p_1} a_{p_1}^+ \int d^3{\vec{p_2}} c_{p_2} a_{p_2}^+ |0 \rangle $$
   for some scalar coefficients $c_{p_1}$ and $c_{p_2}$?
3. If my guess is right, perhaps one can measure the scale $|c_{p_1}|^2$ and $|c_{p_2}|^2$ of the beam. How one can get the phase? We know the beam is localized in the given volume in $V$, but I can't find the explicit way to translate this spatial constraint in terms of the momentums.

Please give me some hints. Thank you.